# Ошибка "Соединение невозможно или разорвано: br-connection-profile-unavailable" в kali linux

Tags: bluetooth, kali-linux

Я хочу подключится к своим наушникам по блютус в kali linux. Мне пишет "Соединение установлено", после чего сразу же "Отключено" и в низу красным текстом пишется "Соединение невозможно или разорвано: br-connection-profile-unavailable". В интернете данной ошибки нету. Там только как исправить демона блютус и тд, всё перепробовал не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

сегодня столкнулся с такой же ошибкой (Linux XUbuntu)
исправление, конкретно у меня было очень простым - я просто удалил устройство из списка bluetooth устройств, после чего добавил его снова

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/776787)